# adding webpart to v4 master in sharepoint2010

Tags: sharepoint

ok, I am trying to use a content editor webpart in my v4.master page. Once I have done this, I then save, check in, and approve the master page. Yet other users still cannot see it! Sharepoint 2010, I am using this method : http://path2sharepoint.wordpress.com/2011/03/02/add-webpart-to-your-master-page/ Any suggestions?!?  Userver in question have read and view only access.

Comment: Are you able to see the changes . If yes did you publish the master page??

Comment: yep master page was published as major version, checked in and approved.

Answer (score 2):

Go to sharepoint designer.

Click on Master pages.

Check if it is default master page, if not then, Right click on your master page and select is as Default Masterpage and Default Custom Master page..